# como ejecutar una funcion de un script sql, desde eclipse con jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

hola estoy haciendo un programa en Eclipse que ejecuta un script SQL, el Script contiene una función llamada:

create or replace procedure inicializa_test is

Esta función esta descrita dentro del script pero no se llega a ejecutar, como puedo llamarla desde Eclipse después de ejecutar el Script con:

ExecuteScript.run("script");

Comment: [Acá](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-run-sql-script-using-jdbc) tienes un tutorial sobre cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.